# Make Cassandra throw exception on primary key collision

Tags: cassandra, primary-key

When I enter a primary key of "abcd" in a table which already has a primary key of "abcd", using an insert statement, Cassandra just updates that record. How do I configure it to throw an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause on the insert which will return an `applied` true or false. This is a lot more expensive and slow though since it requires reading before the write (and a paxos round) while a normal insert never has to check.